# Viewing suggested edits or reviews from user profile redirects to self, breaks "back" feature

Tags: bug, activity-summary, back-button

This is happening to me in IE8 (not able to test in any other browsers at this time).

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to user profile (any user, confirmed on self and other users)
2. Go to activity tab
3. View either "reviews" or "suggestions" sub-tab
4. Click on any of the action links ("close", "suggested edit", etc; not post title) to view the activity
5. Page loads with URL ending in `/{post_id}`, redirects to URL ending in `/{post_id}#./{post_id}?&_suid={suid}`
6. Browser navigation back hits `/{post_id}`, redirects to current page. **It's a trap!**

It's a bit of a pain not being able to use the back feature (although this is not quite as annoying as Google capturing <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, focusing on the search bar, and changing the search results rather than going back).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I no longer experience this bug. If no change was implemented to fix it, it must be confined to non-supported browsers (I no longer use IE8, which I was using when I hit this bug).

Answer (score 2):

I can't repro with FF 14.0.1...

But I *can* with IE7 (I know it's old and unsupported here, but it's what I've got at work).

For the record, in FF, the redirect link is simply `/{post_id}` (doesn't redirect), not the full `/{post_id}#./{post_id}?&_suid={suid}`.

---

FYI, Jim, I can get back by double-clicking the back button to trigger the action before the previous page has time to redirect.

Comment: Right, but it would be nice to be able to only click it once. I've been working around it using the little list of previous pages to go back.